# "edit health check" is greyed out on AWS EC2 Load Balancers

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

The default AWS EC2 Load Balancer Health Check hits "/" but I'd rather have it hit somewhere where. In the Load Balancer settings the "edit health check" is greyed out and I'm not sure why. I continually see ELB-Healthchecker in my access logs. How do I change the health check URL?

```
172.31.46.123 - - [03/Aug/2020:19:03:28 +0900] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 21043 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.12.60 - - [03/Aug/2020:19:03:30 +0900] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 21043 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.46.123 - - [03/Aug/2020:19:03:58 +0900] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 21043 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
172.31.12.60 - - [03/Aug/2020:19:04:00 +0900] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 21043 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0"
```

[image: load balancer list]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your health check is based on a listener that points to an instance group. Go into the instance tab of the ELB, then either create or edit a listener. From there, you point the listener to a target group. The target group has the health checks that you seek:

[image: But who monitors the monitor?]

Comment: Worked great! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

AWS might have changed the EC2 console UI since Wesley answered. I couldn't find the instance tab, but I did find the health check setting by clicking "Target Groups" in the left pane, selecting the desired Target Group, and then clicking the "Health checks" tab.